# Plots shrink after closing and opening the notebook

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I find that every time after I save a notebook and then close and reopen it, the plots and figures will shrink in size compared to the original ones I saved. Is there any way to fix the sizes? Thanks.

**`Before save and close`**

[image: Before close and save]

**`Reopen again`**

[image: Reopen again]

Update:

Q: How did I generate the plots?

A: The ones shown come from complicated functions, but just to illustrate the way I plot:

```
Subscript[\[Rho], 1][r_] := 0.5*r^2*E^(-2 r);
Subscript[\[Rho], 2][r_] := 0.5*r^5*E^(-3 r);
Subscript[\[Rho], 3][r_] := 4 r^4*E^(-4 r);

Plot[{Subscript[\[Rho], 1][r], Subscript[\[Rho], 2][r], 
  Subscript[\[Rho], 3][r]}, {r, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Can you post the code? Are you saving after resizing them manually?

Comment: The small size is probably the correct one.  Because these are all in one cell, and unless you resized it manually (which I don't think you did), it should auto-shrink as a result of the Input style's `ImageSizeMultipliers`.  So the real bug here is that it was ever big to begin with.  That raises the question, then, how did you go about creating this cell?

Comment: @James - From your picture it looks like your plots are part of the **input** cells, not in separate output cells.  Look at the cell brackets [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA2ID.png) - the first plot is part of an output cell, but the second plot I pasted into an input cell and it was resized.

Comment: @JasonB Eureka! The problem arises when I try to copy and paste all the figures from one notebook into another Then those plots are part of the input cells. How can I copy and paste but still maintain their sizes in the new notebook? Thanks.

Comment: @James - I do that all the time, I select all the cells from one notebook using Cmd-A, then just paste them into another notebook.  The problem comes when you first start a new cell in the new notebook, then hit paste *when your cursor is in the new cell*.  This puts all the contents of the old notebook into the new cell of the new notebook.  If you just hit paste without the cursor present, it should recreate all the input and output cells from the old notebook.

Comment: @JasonB It works! Thank you.

Comment: Try fixing the image size: `ImageSize -> 300`.  After this it does not shrink. At least, not in my case.